# SPServices get User ID of a user using SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, spservices

How can I get Userid of a user based on his account name or email using SPServices

I checked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542208/sharepoint-2010-use-spservices-to-get-a-users-id

but this is getting current user id I want to get userid of any user based on there account names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint 2010, you could use JSOM to load the user and retrieve user id by `user.get_id()`

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomFun, "sp.js");
        function CustomFun() {            
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var newUser = context.get_web().ensureUser("contoso\\usera");
            context.load(newUser);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                alert(newUser.get_id());
                alert(newUser.get_title());
            },
            function(sender, args){
                alert(args.get_message());
            });}
```

From SharePoint 2013, I would suggest you use REST api 
https://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: I have SharePoint 2010

Comment: Above script is tested in my local SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Nice worked for me